# jQuery setInterval to continuously update data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have a div class name "tw_marquee_scroller" . I want to update it's data-left value in every 1 second. For example in the first second the value will be 10, then 20,30,40 ....... I am using this code but it's keep returning 10 again and again. What's wrong with this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.tw_marquee_scroller').attr('data-left', 0);

    setInterval(function(){
        var position = parseInt($('.tw_marquee_scroller').data('left'));
        var new_position = position + 10;
        $('.tw_marquee_scroller').attr('data-left', new_position);
        console.log(new_position);
    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: You are overriding jquery by passing "$" as a parameter, $ is undefined.

Comment: @elad.chen No: [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) -> "Aliasing the jQuery Namespace"

Comment: @Andreas Read it to quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try also writing `data` attribute with `data()`, not `attr()`:

```
$('.tw_marquee_scroller').data('left', 0);

setInterval(function(){
    var position = parseInt($('.tw_marquee_scroller').data('left'));
    var new_position = position + 10;
    $('.tw_marquee_scroller').data('left', new_position);
    console.log(new_position);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: @user1936285 nice! Try always manage your `data` attributes like that.

Answer (score 0):

why you didn't take the value in the same way?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.tw_marquee_scroller').attr('data-left', 0);

    setInterval(function(){
        var position = parseInt($('.tw_marquee_scroller').attr('data-left'));
        var new_position = position + 10;
        $('.tw_marquee_scroller').attr('data-left', new_position);
        console.log(new_position);
    }, 1000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `data('left')` in that line to:

```
 var position = parseInt($('.tw_marquee_scroller').attr('data-left'))
```

And it will work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a less window-polluting-shorter approach:

```
$( (function($) {
var scroller = $('.tw_marquee_scroller');

scroller.data('left', 0);

setInterval( function() {
    scroller.data('left', parseInt( scroller.data('left'), 10 ) + 10 );
    console.log( scroller.data("left") );
}, 1000 );

}(jQuery.noConflict())) )
```